# Reading extract from txt file to develop time series file

Tags: fortran

I am trying to develop a code to read a text file from model out puts which is in this format

```
SWMM5 Interface File
Angus Road- City of Mitcham 
60   - reporting time step in sec
2    - number of constituents as listed below:
FLOW CMS
TSS MG/L
1    - number of nodes as listed below:
Outfall1
Node             Year Mon Day Hr  Min Sec FLOW       TSS       
Outfall1         2015 12  09  12  25  00  0.000000   0.000000  
Outfall1         2015 12  09  12  26  00  0.000000   0.000000  
Outfall1         2015 12  09  12  27  00  0.000000   0.000000  
Outfall1         2015 12  09  12  28  00  0.000000   0.000000  
Outfall1         2015 12  09  12  29  00  0.000000   0.000000  
Outfall1         2015 12  09  12  30  00  0.000000   0.000000
```

I am trying to make a text file in the following format

```
outfall1 12/09/2015 12:26:00 0.000000
```

i.e. location date time flow

any suggestions for this ???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I focused just on reading part. Suppose I have your file named test.txt, I would read it like this:

```
program read_test

implicit none
integer :: i !iteration
integer :: number_of_read_lines 
integer :: number_of_forgotten_lines
character ::  forgotten_line*5
character ::  node*12
integer :: time(6)
real :: x(2)
number_of_forgotten_lines=9
number_of_read_lines=3

open (22, FILE='test.txt', STATUS='OLD')
   ! I do not care what I read here, simple jump the lines  
    do i=1,number_of_forgotten_lines
        read(22,*) forgotten_line
    end do

  ! here I read the data   
    do i=1,number_of_read_lines
    ! I think it is easier to read without format specification,
    ! though type of variable must be correct!
      read(22,*)  node,time,x
      ! test what you read, here it is usually better to use format specification
      print*, i,node,time,x
    end do
close (22)

end program
```

Comment: This line `read(22,*) node,time(1),time(2),time(3),time(4),time(5),time(6),x(1),x(2)` could probably be usefully abbreviated to `read(22,*) node, time, x`.